# How to reverse a listobject in Webcenter Sites without scriptlet?

Tags: webcenter-sites

I need iterate over a [listobject](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e39371/JSP/ics-listloop.html) in webcenter sites on **reverse way**, **without use scriptlets**, there are a option (atribute or another tag) to make this possible?

I think that don't need really a example, but this is how I used to iterate a list:

```
<ics:listloop listname="mylist">
    //element tratament
</ics:listloop>
```

Edit: I am thinking about create a new tag but I want know if its possible make this using webcenter sites tags or jstl.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.. check the tag reference where it is mentioned that you can use startrow and endrow attribute in ics:listloop tag. So just provide correct values.. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how read with listloop a List of Attributes or ID's of asset

```
// start Loot with the list

    <ics:listloop listname="ListAsset_Attribute">
    <ics:listget listname="ListAsset_Attribute" fieldname="value" output="Var_ValueOfAttribute" />  

    // Do anything with the values of that id like set an asset
    <assetset:setasset name="varAsset" type='Type_of_Asset' id='<%=ics.GetVar("assetId") %>' />

    </ics:listloop>
```

Read this Link:
https://kksays.wordpress.com/tag/icslistloop/